# Is Ubuntu 10.04 compatible with ASUS Sabertooth P67 motherboard?

Tags: 10.04, hardware

I am building a new PC and consider using a ASUS Sabertooth P67 motherboard. I want to install Ubuntu 10.04, as this release is supported to 2013. I have done some research on the web, but I cannot find anything on how well the motherboard works with Ubuntu 10.04.

Are anyone using this motherboard that can tell if it works well out of the box with Ubuntu 10.04?

Comment: I'm running 11.04 on an ASUS Sabertooth X58 and have no issues. It's not the same model, but it is the same brand and product line.

Comment: I have that motherboard. I just tested it with the 10.04.3 live disk. The Network interface failed to be recognized.

Answer (score 1):

I've 2 asus mo P-series and all work perfectly :)
The bet way to see if it works is to try Ubuntu with live-cd ;)

Answer (score 0):

Updated BIOS to the latest version and I'm having no problems anymore with 11.04 x64 & x86. If you still want to know, I can test 10.10; just ask.